# Error loading design modelsim PE student edition 10.4

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I'm creating a new project which i called alpha,then i create a new file test.vhd.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity d_latch is 
port(
data_in:in std_logic;
data_out:out std_logic;
enable:in std_logic);
end d_latch;

architecture beh of d_latch is 
begin
process(data_in,enable)
    begin
     if(enable <= '1') then 
        data_out <= data_in;
      end if;
    end process;
end beh;
```

I add test.vhd to the project alpha then i compile the file.After that i simulate->start simulate then i check [+] work library then the module presented in it,but an error's message appears

```
Error loading design
```

Comment: You better create a testbench (so with an empty entity) where you add your d_latch component into it.  Compile that testbench and then run it.

Answer (score 0):

First edit the if statement to get the correct results :

`if(enable <= '1')` must be `if(enable = '1')`

I simulated your code and no errors found. Simulation results was correct.

Just open modelsim software, click file and change directory (for example to the address of test.vhd file)
Then compile test.vhd and simulate it. Sometimes you should close modelsim and do the same stages again, because the library directory may be changed wrongly by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems with Modelsim, even when just making minor changes to the VHDL code and recompiling. One thing that seems to work is to change the port modes from buffer to out or inout, depending on the design.